# zsh completion does not work for "service"

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

When I use `zsh completion` for "service", I only get the default `start` and `stop` completed.

`zsh` completion for "service" is handled by `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_init_d`.

For example, when using completion for `service ssh <TAB>`, it is supposed to parse the ssh startup file in `/etc/init.d/ssh` and get all the case statement, such as:

```
restart)

...

try-restart)
```

but that does not work when there are comments after the case statement

```
restart) ### comment

...

try-restart) ### comment
```

I think the part in `_init_d` that is doing the parsing is this:

```
read -u0 -k2 magic < $script && [[ $magic = '#!' ]] && {
  cmds=( ${(f)"$(< $script)"} )
  cmds=( ${(M)cmds:#[[:blank:]]#${~what}([[:blank:]]#\|[[:blank:]]#${~what})#[[:blank:]]#\)} )
  cmds=( ${${(j:|:s:|:)cmds}//[^-a-z_]} )
}
```

How can i modify it, so that parsing works even when comments are after the case statement ?

Comment: "works" is relative, of course, and this will only ever be a bodge.  It won't work with the "new" 2014 style of van Smoorenburg rc scripts on Debian.  That does not have the verbs in a `case` statement to be parsed in the first place.  More broadly, given that the question is not tied to an operating system or a service management subsystem, it won't work with OpenRC or OpenBSD rc also, for the same reason.  It already tries to deal with Mewburn rc differently, in fact, for this very reason.

Comment: It does not even work for me without the comments.